# I can't clear up this memory leak in my C program

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, compiler-errors

So in my program, I'm being told that I have a memory leak from the following:

> Direct leak of 144 byte(s) in 6 object(s) allocated from:
> #0 0x7f14547bbb40 in __interceptor_malloc 
> #1 0x563579804cfa in getRow /home/runner/WORKING-PA2/main.c:38
> #2 0x563579806040 in invert /home/runner/WORKING-PA2/main.c:162
> #3 0x5635798072ab in main /home/runner/WORKING-PA2/main.c:261
> #4 0x7f14535ecbf6 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)

The following code is from the end of my main function where I am trying to free up everything that I allocated.

```
double ** Xtranspose = transposeMatrix(X, numHouses, numAttributes+1);
double**  Xmult = multiply(Xtranspose,numAttributes+1,numHouses,X, numHouses, numAttributes+1);
double ** invertMatrix = invert(Xmult, numAttributes+1);
double**  invertMult = multiply(invertMatrix, numAttributes+1, numAttributes+1,Xtranspose,numAttributes+1,numHouses);
double**  W = multiply(invertMult, numAttributes+1,numHouses,Y, numHouses, 1);
double**  Yprime = multiply(Xprime, numHouses2, numAttributes2+1,W, numAttributes+1,1);
printMatrix(Yprime,numHouses2, 1);
    
freeMatrix(X, numHouses, numAttributes+1);
freeMatrix(Y,numHouses, 1);
freeMatrix(Xprime, numHouses2, numAttributes2+1);
freeMatrix(Xtranspose, numAttributes+1, numHouses);
freeMatrix(Xmult, numAttributes+1, numAttributes+1);
freeMatrix(invertMatrix, numAttributes+1,numAttributes+1);
freeMatrix(invertMult, numAttributes+1,numHouses);
freeMatrix(W, numAttributes+1,1);
freeMatrix(Yprime,numHouses2, 1);
```

Here is the invert function:

```
double ** invert(double **matrix, int size){
    double ** identity = allocateMatrix(size, size);
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j =0;j<size;j++){
            if(i==j){
                identity[i][j] = 1.0;
            }
            else{
                identity[i][j] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int j =0;j<size;j++){
        double * currentRow = getRow(size, j,matrix);
        double * currentRow2 = getRow(size, j,identity);
    
        if(matrix[j][j]==0){
            printMatrix(matrix,size,size);
            int a = j+1;
            while(a<size){
                if(matrix[a][j]!=0){
                    break;
                }
                a++;
            }
    
            double * otherRow2 = getRow(size, a, identity);
            otherRow2 = multiplyRowByScalar(size, otherRow2, 1/matrix[a][j]);
            otherRow2 = addRows(size,currentRow2, otherRow2);
            identity = setRow(size, j, identity, otherRow2);
    
            double * otherRow = getRow(size, a, matrix);
            otherRow = multiplyRowByScalar(size, otherRow, 1/matrix[a][j]);
            otherRow = addRows(size,currentRow, otherRow);
            matrix = setRow(size, j, matrix, otherRow);
    
            free(otherRow);
            free(otherRow2);
        }
        else if(matrix[j][j]==1){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            currentRow2 = multiplyRowByScalar(size, currentRow2, 1/matrix[j][j]);
            identity = setRow(size, j, identity, currentRow2);
    
            currentRow = multiplyRowByScalar(size, currentRow, 1/matrix[j][j]);
            matrix = setRow(size, j, matrix, currentRow);
        }
    
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            currentRow = getRow(size, i,matrix);
            currentRow2 = getRow(size, i,identity);
    
            if(i!=j){
                if(matrix[i][j]!=0){
                    double * pivotRow2 = getRow(size, j,identity);
                    pivotRow2 = multiplyRowByScalar(size, pivotRow2, -matrix[i][j]);
                    currentRow2 = addRows(size,pivotRow2, currentRow2);
                    identity = setRow(size, i, identity, currentRow2);
    
                    double * pivotRow = getRow(size, j,matrix);
    
                    pivotRow = multiplyRowByScalar(size, pivotRow, -matrix[i][j]);
    
                    currentRow = addRows(size,pivotRow, currentRow);
                    matrix = setRow(size, i, matrix, currentRow);
                }
            }
    
            free(currentRow);
            free(currentRow2);
        }
    }
    return identity;
}
```

Here is the getRow function:

```
double *getRow(int size, int rowNum, double **matrix){
  double *row = malloc(sizeof(double*)*size);
  for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
    row[i] =matrix[rowNum][i];
  }
  return row;
}
```

Something is wrong with the way that the data in main isn't freeing from the getRow and invert function im pretty sure, but I cannot figure out why it isn't getting freed. I have tried throwing free and free loops all over, but the bytes remain leaked.

Comment: Please remove all code not needed to repro the problem to produce a [mre]. Specifically try first to repro with only the allocation and free calls and everything else stripped out. Producing minimal code is not only required for SO questions but is also a standard and effective way to debug.

Comment: It looks like first allocations of `currentRow` and `currentRow2` in `invert` are either never freed or lost because something else is assigned to them. The error tells you the line number where the allocation happens. Look there.

Comment: Do `multiplyRowByScalar` or `addRows` allocate new arrays? You're reassigning the variables with the results of these, so you leak the old memory that they pointed to.

Comment: @Barmar neither of those functions allocate any new arrays

Comment: @RetiredNinja currentRow and currentRow2 do get freed later on in invert, but do I have to free them again at some point earlier up in the function?

Comment: You reassign them in the `for` loop.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use 2D arrays instead of this fragmented, leaky stuff? `double (*matrix)[y] = malloc( sizeof(double[x][y]) ); ... matrix[i][j] = something; ... free(matrix);`

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is reassigning `currentRow` and `currentRow2`, but you never freed their old values. So add

```
free(currentRow);
free(currentRow2);
```

before the loop.

You also never free `pivotRow` and `pivotRow2`. You need to free them at the end of the `if(matrix[i][j]!=0){` block.

Comment: So this cleared 2 of the 4 errors. The other 2 are still pointing to lines 171 and 172, which are currentRow= getRow(size, i, matrix); and currentRow2 = getRow(size, i, identity);. These are the lines in the next for loop directly after what I added. Whats confusing however is that the current row variables do get freed already at the end of this loop

Comment: Why do you reassign the variables if they don't allocate new memory?

Comment: I think you've got the line numbers wrong. The problem is that you never free `pivotRow` and `pivotRow2`.

Comment: When I attempt to free those, it tells me im double freeing

Comment: Are they being freed in the functions that you call? it's really hard to tell what's being allocated and free automatically.

Comment: No, the pivots are not brought up anywhere else outside of the invert function. Thats the only reference

Comment: then I don't see how they can be double freed.

Comment: They're being passed as arguments to `multiplyRowByScalar` and `addRows`. It's not freeing those parameters?

Comment: They are being passed to those functions, but they shouldn't be messing with the memory. I am honestly not sure why the address sanitizer is pointing to the lines that it is

Comment: This is the best anwer I can give with the limited information I have.

Comment: Am I able to private message you the full code? I didn't want to just paste the whole thing here

Comment: I'm not going to try to analyze hundreds of lines of code ilke this. Sorry.

Comment: @GopeS. In addition to the issues pointed out by Barmar, this is wrong too: `double *row = malloc(sizeof(double*)*size);` To allocate an array, you would do `sizeof(double)` instead. To allocate an array of pointers, you have to do `double** row =  ...`. Hint: some 95% of all memory leak/heap corruption questions on SO can be explained by bad parameters passed to malloc.

Comment: @GopeS. General rule: When you use `sizeof(type)` in the `malloc()` call, the type should have 1 less `*` than the variable type you're assigning to. But many prefer to use `sizeof(*variable)` rather than `sizeof(type)`, since no counting or subtraction are required.